# Statement is returning false when it shouldn't

Tags: php

The following statement returns `false` for some reason:

```
$coin = isset($_GET['market']) ? $_GET['market'] : 'BTC_USD';
echo $coin;
if($this->model->coins($coin) == false):
    $coin = 'BTC_USD';
else:
    $coin = $_GET['market'];
endif;
```

Model:

```
public function coins($coin)
{   
    $coins = array("BTC_USD","BTC_GBP","LTC_USD","LTC_GBP","BTC_LTC","USD_GBP");
    if (!in_array($coin, $coins))
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

If I `echo` the `$coin` before the `if` statement it returns the correct coin, but after the `if` statement it's returning `false`. I know it's an easy fix, it's just bypassing me completely. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `coins()` method never returns `true`. When it doesn't return `false`, it returns `undefined` because there's no alternative `return` statement. Since you're doing a loose comparison in the caller, `undefined == false`. Change the method to:

```
public function coins($coin)
{   
    $coins = array("BTC_USD","BTC_GBP","LTC_USD","LTC_GBP","BTC_LTC","USD_GBP");
    return in_array($coin, $coins));
}
```